# Using Autofac with HostApplicationBuilder

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, autofac, worker

I am building a new .net 8 worker service and microsoft has modified the generic host. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host?tabs=appbuilder)

```
HostApplicationBuilder builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
```

instead of the older

```
IHostBuilder builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
});
```

The issue being that I can't seem to find the correct syntax for registering autofac as the service factory on a HostApplicationbuilder instead of an IHostbuilder as shown here [Autofac Documentation](https://github.com/autofac/Examples/blob/master/src/GenericHostBuilderExample/Program.cs)

I have a working asp.net 8 project that works with the new WebApplicationBuilder

```
builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
    .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder => builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacBuilder(settings)));
```

and I would like to use a similar pattern for this console worker application.

Can anyone provide advice on the correct way to register an Autofac and an Autofac Module as the service provider for a HostApplicationBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

Autofac can be registered as the ServiceProviderFactory for a HostApplicationBuilder via:

```
builder.ConfigureContainer(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory(), builder => builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacBuilder(settings)));
```